# How to logout from community portal in Salesforce

Tags: visualforce

I am working on Sites and want to implement logout functionality and redirect to custom login page. I used the scripts but they are redirecting me to standard login page..

/secur/logout.jsp?retUrl=/WPLogin

{!$Site.Prefix}/secur/logout.jsp

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Site and replace existing standard login page with custom login page

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!$Site.Prefix}/secur/logout.jsp" styleClass="nav0-link">Logout</apex:outputLink>
```

Comment: **<apex:outputLink value="{!$Site.Prefix}/secur/logout.jsp" styleClass="nav0-link">Logout</apex:outputLink>**

Comment: function redirectToLogin(){ 
window.parent.location.href = <desired url> ; 
} 
function logoutMe(){ 
$("#logoutDiv").html("<iframe src='" + "{!$Site.Prefix}/secur/logout.jsp" + "'><iframe>"); 
setTimeout("redirectToLogin()", 500); 
} 
<div id="logoutDiv" style="display:none"/> 
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="logoutMe();" > Logout </a>